# Is it possible to have multiple greater rift keystones at once

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a Greater Rift Keystone that I use for running with my wife, but I also want to get one for when I solo.

Is it possible to have multiple Greater Rift Keystones on same character at once?

Comment: yes. 11 more to go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly possible. Every time you kill a Rift Guardian in a normal Nephalem Rift, you get a chance (up to 100% chance in Torment 6) to recieve a Greater Rift key stone. They stack in your inventory by level : up to stack of 100, after 100 you start a new stack. It also means you can have several Keystone of the same level at once.

Example :

[image]